# Сенсорный ввод - манипуляции

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8

Разбираюсь с обработкой сенсорного ввода в wpf, нашёл код который по идее подключает обработку стандартных жестов windows для 3 фотографий лежащих на canvas. Но при запуске ничего не работает: фотки не изменяют размера, не перетаскиваются - ничего не делают.xaml:

```
<Canvas Name="cnv">
        <Image Source="img1.jpg" Width="300" IsManipulationEnabled="True"
               Canvas.Top="10" Canvas.Left="42" ManipulationDelta="Image_ManipulationDelta"
               ManipulationStarting="Image_ManipulationStarting">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <MatrixTransform></MatrixTransform>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
        <Image Source="img2.jpg" Width="292" Canvas.ZIndex="1" IsManipulationEnabled="True"
               Canvas.Top="200" Canvas.Left="230" ManipulationDelta="Image_ManipulationDelta"
               ManipulationStarting="Image_ManipulationStarting">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <MatrixTransform></MatrixTransform>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
        <Image Source="img3.jpg" Width="300" IsManipulationEnabled="True"
               Canvas.Top="18" Canvas.Left="419" ManipulationDelta="Image_ManipulationDelta" 
               ManipulationStarting="Image_ManipulationStarting">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <MatrixTransform></MatrixTransform>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
</Canvas>
```

код С#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication10
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Image_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
        {
            UIElement element = (UIElement)e.Source;
// Манипуляция с внешним видом элемента и его позицией
            Matrix matrix = ((MatrixTransform)element.RenderTransform).Matrix;
            ManipulationDelta md = e.DeltaManipulation;
        }

        private void Image_ManipulationStarting(object sender, ManipulationStartingEventArgs e)
        {
            // Указываем базовый контейнер
            e.ManipulationContainer = cnv;

            // Указание разрешенных манипуляций
            e.Mode = ManipulationModes.All;
        }
    }
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так, и где можно почтиать про манимуляции и сенсорный ввод? Желательно на русском и с примерами.